# Unit Testing ActualWidth in control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I am creating a custom control that uses a `Canvas` that I call `_grid` and I am trying to unit test some methods in my manager class that I have created. All of my unit tests are failing because of the `_grid.ActualWidth` and `_grid.ActualHeight` are 0;

```
public RowColumnManagerTests()
{
    _grid = new Canvas() { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
    _grid.BeginInit();
    _grid.EndInit();
    _sut = new RowColumnManager(_grid, new Style(typeof(Border)), 3.0, () => 10);
}

[StaTheory]
[ClassData(typeof(RowCountData))]
public void RowCount_ShouldAddUpdateRowsInConfigure_WhenChanged(int initialCount, int targetAmount)
{
    //arrange
    _sut.RowCount = initialCount;
    var count = CountRows();
    _sut.RowCount.Should().Be(count);
    
    //act
    _sut.RowCount = targetAmount;
    
    //assert
    _sut.RowCount.Should().Be(targetAmount);
    var newCount = CountRows();
    newCount.Should().Be(_sut.RowCount);
}
```

As you can see I set the width property, I cannot set the `ActualWidth` and the `ActualHeight` properties do not have a setter.

How can I set them?

Comment: You don't set `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight`.  They are set for you.   The documentation explains this pretty clearly.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: And just a suggestion to prevent confusion for others:  Don't name a `Canvas` control  `_grid`.  Name it `_canvas` or something like that.  There's already a `Grid` control

Comment: It's rare to unit test Wpf UI . Much more usual to unit test models and viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question, the answer is

```
   _grid = new Canvas() { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
   _grid.RenderSize = new Size(100.0, 100.0);
```